# Renaming files after Yeoman copies template files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am working on a sample yeoman generator based on Yeoman's [generator-generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator). The default `writing` function generated is like this:

```
generators.Base.extend({
    writing: function () {
        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.sourceRoot(),
            this.destinationRoot());
    }
});
```

My template files contain Visual Studio project and solution files so I wish to rename them to match `appName`:

```
generators.Base.extend({
    writing: function () {
        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.sourceRoot(),
            this.destinationRoot(),
            { appname: this.props.appName });

        // Rename directory to match 'appName'
        this.fs.move(
            this.destinationPath('foo'), // A directory
            this.detinationPath(this.props.appName)); // From prompt when user types yo webapp

        // Rename Visual Studio .sln file to match 'appName'
        this.fs.move(
            this.destinationPath('foo/bar.sln'),
            this.destinationPath(this.props.appName + '/' + this.props.appName + '.sln');

       // ...similar renames to Visual Studio .csproj files
    }
});
```

However, I get an Assertion error at the line that does the first `move`:

```
AssertionError: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist
```

I thought the file/directory copying is synchronous but when I ran `this.fs.exists(this.destinationRoot())` before the first call to `this.fs.move` it returns `false`. I suspect it is something to do with `this.fs` being an instance of an [mem-fs](https://github.com/sboudrias/mem-fs) where the directory/files only exist in memory until the `writing` function completes.

What can I do if I need to rename files/directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it works if you use a glob pattern in your copy function?

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath('**'),
        this.destinationPath(),
        { appname: this.props.appName });
```

mem-fs operations are synchronous and the exist check will pass if the files are really copied over.

Comment: Doesn't `this.sourceRoot('**')` modifies the `sourceRoot`?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I copy pasted your code. But then the issue is mixing the root functions with the path creators. You need to use `this.templatePath()` and `this.destinationPath()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247600/renaming-single-file-names-while-copying-entire-folder-using-copytpl/39276789#39276789 sounds like what you need?