# Renaming single file names while copying entire folder using copyTpl

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

My yeoman generator copies files from template to destination path:

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath(),
            this.destinationPath(), {
                appName: this.props.appName
            });
```

During project generation, I need to assign value of `this.props.appName` to some of filenames.

Unfortunately I can't do this that way like I could do inside this files:

```
<%=appName%>-project.sln
```

All files that need to be renamed have `appTemplate` in their names, so what I need to do is simply replace `appTemplate` with value of `this.props.appName`.

Can I somehow configure `copyTpl` to rename some of files while copying them to another destination?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy all files but change the name of some automatically in yeoman](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155182/copy-all-files-but-change-the-name-of-some-automatically-in-yeoman)

Answer (score 9):

OK, I found a solution. According to [yeoman docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html):

> Any generator author can register a transformStream to modify the file path and/or the content.

Using this method:

```
this.registerTransformStream();
```

What that means is I can pipe all generated files through some script:

```
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
//other dependecies...

module.exports = yeoman.Base.extend({

    //some other things generator do...

    writing: function() {
        var THAT = this;
        this.registerTransformStream(rename(function(path) {
            path.basename = path.basename.replace(/(666replacethat666)/g, THAT.props.appName);
            path.dirname = path.dirname.replace(/(666replacethat666)/g, THAT.props.appName);
        }));
        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath(),
            this.destinationPath(), {
                appName: this.props.appName
            });
    }
});
```

This script will pipe all files through [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename), changing `666replacethat666` to something more intelligent.

Comment: Brilliant, didn't use THAT in the end, just access props directly.

Comment: lastest gulp-rename did not work for me, but only version 1.2.2. - got the hint from here: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/577#issuecomment-392325341

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `registerTransformStream` because you are using the `composeWith()` feature in Yeoman (which disconnects transform stream registrations), you can use the `processDestinationPath`, which works when you select multiple files (not when you specify a specific file in the first argument, for some reason).

```js
this.fs.copyTpl(
  this.templatePath("**/{.*,*}"),
  this.destinationPath(),
  { /* usually your prompt answers are here */ },
  {},
  {
    processDestinationPath: (filePath: string) =>
      filePath.replace(/somedir\/a-file.js/g, 'newdir/better-filename.js'),
  },
);
```

Source to documentation options: https://yeoman.github.io/generator/actions_fs.html#.copyTemplate

Which is based on https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor#copyfrom-to-options-context-templateoptions-

Answer (score 0):

`registerTransformStream` with `gulp-rename` is still an issue. However, I get it working with glob.

```
const glob = require('glob');

writing() {
    const files = glob.sync('**', { dot: true, nodir: true, cwd: this.templatePath() })
    for (let i in files) {
        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath(files[i]),
            this.destinationPath( this.props.destinationFolderPath + '\\' + files[i].replace(/__fileName__/g,this.props.fileName)),
            this.props
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After copy, iterate over the paths of the output dir and regex replace all occurrences.

```
const getReplacement = (base, pathRel, match, replace) => {
  let pathRelNew = pathRel.replace(match, replace);

  let oldPathAbs = path.join(base, pathRel);
  let newPathAbs = path.join(base, pathRelNew);

  if (oldPathAbs != newPathAbs) {
    return {
      oldPath: oldPathAbs,
      newPath: newPathAbs
    }
  }
}

const getReplacementsRecursive = (base, match, replace, replacements = []) => {
  let pathsRel = fs.readdirSync(base);

  pathsRel.forEach(pathRel => {
    if (fs.statSync(path.join(base, pathRel)).isDirectory()) {
      replacements = getReplacementsRecursive(path.join(base, pathRel), match, replace, replacements);

      var replacement = getReplacement(base, pathRel, match, replace)
      if (replacement) replacements.push(replacement);
    } else {
      var replacement = getReplacement(base, pathRel, match, replace)
      if (replacement) replacements.push(replacement);
    }
  });

  return replacements;
};

function replaceMatches(dir, match, replace) {
  var replacements = getReplacementsRecursive(dir, match, replace);

  replacements.forEach(function(replacement) {
    fs.renameSync(replacement.oldPath, replacement.newPath);
  });
}

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  // ...

  writing() {
    // don't forget to set the output directory
    let OUTPUT_DIR = "./out";

    // this.fs.copyTpl(...);

    // setTimeout is used to give some time for the copyTpl to finish
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        var match = new RegExp( "666replacethat666", 'g' );
        replaceMatches(OUTPUT_DIR, match, this.props.appName);
      }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend simply renaming the destination files after your template operation.

I got this solution from this discussion:  [Renaming files after Yeoman copies template files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35484645/89176)

Example:

```js
// start by doing the large template operation with a glob
this.fs.copyTpl(
    this.templatePath("**/*"),
    this.destinationPath(),
    this.answers,
);

// Example of a directory rename - moving the ApplicationName directory and everything in it
this.fs.move(
    this.destinationPath('src', 'ApplicationName', '**/*'),
    this.destinationPath('src', this.answers.appName, '**/*')
);

// Renaming a single file.  Note how we are now operating within the renamed directory
this.fs.move(
    this.destinationPath('src', this.answers.appName, 'ApplicationName.csproj'), 
    this.destinationPath('src', this.answers.appName, this.answers.appName + '.csproj')
);
```